# DATA attribute for image created from src image

Tags: src, attr

I want to add to the photo the attributes "data-full" and "data-thumb" containing the image address. So for example:

```
<img data-full="images/photo.jpg" data-thumb="images/photo.jpg" src="images/photo.jpg">
```

Unfortunately, my attempts end in a failure.

Please help me.

Comment: Is it in PHP or Jquery?

Comment: What kind of failure? data-full and data-thumb are not defined in html specification, so the expected behaviour is: nothing (= displaying the image in the browser because of `<img src=>`). Now, we need to know what do _you_ expect and why (for example because you use "that library") or similar. And then you need to tell us what is "my attempts end in a failure": A browser crash? A blue screen? A message box?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery then you can do it like this:

This is your html

```
<img id="myPhoto" src="images/photo.jpg">
```

Then in your jquery

```
$(#myPhoto).attr('data-full', 'images/photo.jpg');
$(#myPhoto).attr('data-thumb', 'images/photo.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the delay with the response. I thought I was going to be notified that someone wrote something in the subject.

I want to implement https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumogallery to my website.
"My attempt end in a failure." That means I can not write well.

No. My html is:

```
...
<li><img src="images/o6/photo.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="images/o7/photo2.png"></li>
<li><img src="images/23/image1245.jpg"></li>
...
```

Image addresses are different because they are from different directories.
I would like to receive the result:

```
...
<li><img data-full="images/o6/photo.jpg" data-thumb="images/o6/photo.jpg" src="images/o6/photo.jpg"></li>
<li><img data-full="images/o7/photo2.png" data-thumb="images/o7/photo2.png" src="images/o7/photo2.png"></li>
<li><img data-full="images/23/image1245.jpg" data-thumb="images/23/image1245.jpg" src="images/23/image1245.jpg"></li>
...
```